# values from session is not passed to next endpoint in a scenario in gatling script

Tags: performance, session, gatling

From a gatling senario making endpoint calls, where saving jobIds response from initiate endpoint into session and need to pass jobIds retrived from it to next endpoint call. However those values are not picked in call back endpoint.

code snippet:

```
var testScenario:ScenarioBuilder=scenario("Test Scenario")
            .exec(testObj.initiateEndpoint())
            .pause("8")
            .exec(session => {

                var jobId1: String = null
                var jobId2: String = null
                val jobIds = session(BulkConstants.JOB_IDS).as[Vector[String]]

                if (jobIds != null && jobIds.size > 0) {
                    jobId1 = bulkJobIds(0)
                            println("************JobID1************", jobId1)
                            jobId2 = bulkJobIds(1)
                            println("************JobID2************", jobId2)
                }
                if(jobId1 != null && jobId2 != null)
                    session.set("jobId1", jobId1).set("jobId2", jobId2)
                    else
                        session
            })

            .exec(testObj.callBack("${jobId1}"))
            .pause("2")

            .exec(testObj.callBack("${jobId2}"))
            .pause("2")
```

when I try to print values or use them in callBack(String jobId), it simply prints "${jobId1}" and not the passed value. what could be wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

[Gatling Expression Language doesn't work in your custom code](https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/core/session/el/).

You must use the [Session API](https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/core/session/session_api/).

Comment: That helped! wrapping custom code to session and then calling endpoint.